# MvvmCross hang after MvxApplication.Initialize() from lock screen on Moto G Play

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

This is a very specific problem. On a Motorola Moto G Play we have an app running with Firebase Push Notifications. Now this is the situation:

- App is not running
- Lock screen is on
- Message received from Firebase
- Icon appears on lock screen
- Slide the icon up
- App starts
- Hangs after Initialize() in the MvxApplication class

I'm unable to see exactly where the hang takes place. This does not happen when the app is started from the tray after unlocking or starting the app from the desktop.

Comment: The last method called is the InitializeFirstChange() from the MainApplication. After that the App hangs. The next should have been the GetViewModelAssemblies() from Setup.cs but it never gets there.

Comment: It seems to be somehow related to Firebase.

Comment: I've still not been able to solve this problem. The main reason is that I cannot debug it because it happens at startup. I have to rely on log information and that is a poor tool. Does any know how to debug an App on Android from startup?